# how to change the inflater of my KeyboardView

Tags: android, ime, layout-inflater

I am developing an IME for android.
i have the options of setting the theme for the keyboard.
the problem when i try to inflate the keyboardView a second time it it did not work

KeyboardView  k = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input1, null);

it change just when i re-runing the app .

it seems is just changed when the my InputMethodeService recreated but i did not found a way to stop it and start the service again.

Plz Help

Comment: Please be more clear on how it did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

the first inflate work but when i try to inflate the keyboardView when the them settings change the keyboard keep the first layout inflate.

Comment: have you found a way to achieve that? I also need this for keyboard themes.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem.

My real problem is to inflate the same view ( KeyboardView ) multiple time.

I tried to change my parent view from KeyboardView to a RelativeLayout and for each keyboardveiw Theme i Remove all the parent child and i add the new keyboardview infalted with the new Theme.